# No command specified for process type web in heroku release docker image

Tags: image, docker, heroku, containers, release

I have a problem with deploy my docker image with my application in heroku Container Registry.
  My application packed to a docker image. It mapped to work by port 8085. But also I have to provide to test my application on heroku.

My playback steps are:
1. heroku login.

2. heroku container login.
3. heroku create my-app.
4. docker tag my-image registry.heroku.com/my-app/web.
5. docker push registry.heroku.com/my-app/web.
6. Setting environment variables:

SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP:1521:xe

SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: apiusername

SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: apiuserpassword

SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER-CLASS-NAME: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

SPRING_JPA_DATABASE-PLATFORM: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect

SPRING_DATASOURCE_TYPE: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource

SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL-AUTO: update

PORT: 8085

JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m

7. heroku container:release web --app my-app

After this step I have an error:

Releasing images web to my-app... !
 ▸    No command specified for process type web

what am I doing wrong?